# TypeError is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm currently playing around with `Nodes.js` and creating a simple bot as a proof on concept. I'm using the `discord.js` package.

I have the following codes

```
// FluffBot class initialisation
var FluffBot = function Constructor(settings, commands) {
    this.settings = settings
    this.commands = commands
}

// Run bot
FluffBot.prototype.run = function() {
    discord = new discord.Client()
    discord.loginWithToken(this.settings.bot_token)
    discord.on('ready', function(event) {
        FluffBot._onReady(event)
    })
}

// On ready function
FluffBot.prototype._onReady = function(event) {
    discord.setPlayingGame('Alpha v1.0')
    this.watcher()
}
```

I am initiating the run function in another js file but am getting the following error

`TypeError: FluffBot._onReady is not a function at Client.<anonymous>`

Any ideas on getting it to call the function would be awesome.

Comment: My guess is that due to calling a event listener i'd new to instantiate a new version of the bot. Decided to refactor it so that the event listeners call code as needed rather than trying to do everything in the one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure FluffBot is is instantiated with the `new` keyword?

You could add this to prevent:

```
if (!(this instanceof FluffBot)) {
  return new FluffBot()
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that as it apart of the same Class which was instantiated to call run that calling ._onReady would be ok